# maven release component: trunk and tag on different repositories

Tags: java, maven, svn

Just a little question..

Assuming that we have the trunk of our component on a SVN repo

(http://svn1.svn1:9883/svn/test/trunk/component)

And I want to release (with maven release plugin) this component, but i want the tag in a different SVN repo in a different environment, like

(http://svn2.svn2:8888/svn/test/tags/component)

Is it possible using the maven release plugin???

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the intention to put the tag into a different repository than the trunk located which does not make sense at all nor is supported by Subversion neither by Maven.

Comment: I don't think so. The tag base for the release plugin can be configured: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#tagBase - but as far as I know svn will not like that. It may be possible using svn externals to achieve this so maven sees only one svn repository.

Comment: See [Wikipedia, Subversion, Branching and tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion#Branching_and_tagging): _"The copied directory is linked to the original in the repository to preserve its history,"_ - I'd rather not tinker with linked repository parts, though it might be possible technically. But it's your decision how precious you consider your data at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much..As I supposed, it's SVN that does not support this features (only with SVN externals). About the Khamarbaise comment...I think the same, you have to ask to my Boss! :)